# How to delete hstr command history

Tags: command-history

I have the program [`hstr`](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr) installed.

Is there a way to delete all commands from `hstr`?

Using `history -c` doesn't affect `hstr` and I can't find anything in the man to  delete more than a single command at a time from `hstr`. This seems like an oversight, as clearing your entire history seems like a common task.

Is there any way to clear the entire `hstr` command history?

I also have an additional question when using the normal `history` command:

When I do `history -c` the command history is deleted which can be seen by running `history` again. However, when I open up a new terminal and run `history` suddenly there are many commands back in my history.

Are the commands being persisted somehow? How do I prevent the commands from re-populating after running `history -c`?

Comment: README.md > **Bugs** → https://github.com/dvorka/hstr/issues → Delete history item >>> https://github.com/dvorka/hstr/issues/386

Comment: While I can confirm this bug is reproducible, it isn't related to my question.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to delete the history with the following command

```
$ rm ~/.bash_history
```

After deleting the history, the *hstr* tool will also have the history cleared. (It shares it's history with the normal *history* command).

Closing and re-opening a new terminal confirms that the history stays deleted. This can be confirmed by running *hstr* or *history*.

Note that the *hstr* command has no native option to delete all history. It must be deleted using *history -c*, or, in my case, *rm ~/.bash_history* since I have persistent history setup between shells and therefore *history -c* doesn't work.

You can delete *hstr* entries one by one using the DEL key from within *hstr*

---

Note that the bug mentioned in the comment above (https://github.com/dvorka/hstr/issues/386) is not relevant here. I confirmed this bug exists (it's reproducible) but it doesn't relate to my question. The strange part about this bug, is the command referenced in the bug, *history -r*, is not actually a part of the history command on Debian which is History GNU version 6.3, which the man file can be found here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/history.3.html (Note that there is no -r option)

*history -r* appears to be part of a *different* version of history, although one which I can not find nor know anything more about. This man file mentioned -r, but it isn't clear what version of history this is for: https://ss64.com/bash/history.html

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. It is perhaps worthwile to note that while deleting the `.bash_history` does indeed remove the command history "for good", it does not affect commands used in the _current_ bash session, and that these commands will be synced back to that file once the session exits.

Comment: I have updated my answer to be more complete - please let me know if it is sufficient.

Comment: The reference to `history(3)` is irrelevant as that is about some _library_ implementing history management routines (which `bash` may use, but that are irrelevant to a user running the command `history -r`).  Just mentioning this as you seem to be confused by the `history(3)` manual (the `history` command is documented in the shell's manual).

Comment: But when I type `man history` I receive the `history(3)` shown in the terminal. I don't see any man pages that mention `-r`

Comment: @NateHouk That's because `history` is a shell _built-in_ command, not an external command with its own manual. See the manual for `bash` (or for that matter, `help history` in an interactive `bash` shell). See also [Why don't shell builtins have proper man pages?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/167004)

Comment: That makes sense that *history* is a built-in bask command and not an external program. Is there another *history* program which I can install which has the -r option? Which program is the man page located here (https://ss64.com/bash/history.html) for? How do I install that *history* program?